# Dynamically populate Vuex state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I need to load a different version of state based on a `data` variable in the root component.

App.vue:

```
export default {
  store : store,
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    clientId : 1  
  }
}
```

store.js:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state : {
    clientConfig : clientConfig
});
```

And the `clientConfig` would be store in a separate file.

What is the best way to achieve a dynamic/programmatic loading of the Vuex state based on some input to the initial Vuejs App?

Thanks!

Comment: One solution is load all `clientConfig` to your store, and use `getters` to get config corresponding to `clientId`

Comment: yes, but then the whole app would be full of `if client = x {get.config.a}` right or am I missing something?

Comment: You can store `clientId` in `vuex` also. Then just read data from `vuex` store

Comment: A small example would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is 1 possible solution:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state : {
    clientConfigs :{
      "1": clientConfig1,
      "2": clientConfig2
    },
    clientId: "1"
  },
  getters: {
    currentClientConfig: state => {
      return state.clientConfigs[state.clientId]
    }
  },
  mutations: {
   setClientId (state, newValue) {
     state.clientId = newValue
   }
  }
});
```

and in your component, you can access config by `this.$store.getters.currentClientConfig`

To update `clientId`, you can use mutations. In component, you can use
`this.$store.commit('setClientId', yourNewClientId)`

Comment: This looks good - but how do I set `clientId : 1`, right now I was testing a solution using Vue.set() on a component.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can update clientId by `mutations`. For more information https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html

Comment: Amazing thank you! Just one thing, an error is thrown due to the order of loading/rendering - as the template calls the `currentClientConfig `, before it is defined - the app works, but error messages are bad :(